# «5 и 10-рублевые» – как правильно написать?

Tags: числительные, дефис, раздельно-дефис

Как правильно написать числительные в таком случае: «5 и 10 рублевые монеты времен Николая II»?

Comment: Лучше записать *монеты номиналом 5 и 10 рублей*, кроме того десятирублевые пишется одним словом, так что, вероятно, придется писать 5 и 10-рублевые, так как сращение или типа того.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно написать так:
***5- и 10-рублевые монеты времен Николая II***.

Или так:
***пяти- и десятирублевые монеты времен Николая II***.

> **§ 112.** Дефис применяется при записи конструкций с однородными членами, имеющими общий конечный элемент, если все члены, кроме последнего, представлены только начальными элементами; такой дефис называют «висячим», напр.: *шарико- и роликоподшипники; лит- и изокружки; кино-, теле- и видеофильмы...*
> [[Справочник под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59)]

Орфографический словарь (Грамота.ру):
[**пятирублёвый (5-рублёвый)**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9F%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9);
[**десятирублёвый (10-рублёвый)**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x).